# Problemas al enviar correos con PHPMailer

Tags: php

Se me altera el color del texto, que hay en el correo, cuando lo envió la primera vez llega de color negro, pero cuando lo envió una segunda vez y se ajunta en el mismo correo el de abajo aparece con un color morado.
Envió 1ra vez;[image: Imagen de lo que llega al correo]

Código del PHPMailer que uso para enviar los correo, lo llamo dos veces.

```
public function sendEmail(){
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $instructorLider = mb_convert_case($nomLider, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
    $instructor = mb_convert_case($nomInstructor, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");

    $mensaje = "PRIMER TEXTO, SI HAGO UN SALTO DE LINEA, EN EL SEGUNDO TEXTO APARECE MORADO, PERO NO
    EN EL PRIMERO <BR> SEGUNDO TEXTO, LA PRIMERA VEZ LLEGA BIEN LA SEGUNDA APARECE EL TEXTO CON SALTO MORADO.";
   // $mensaje = "HOLA AMIGOS COMO ESTAIS EH?";
    $mail->Username ='aooo@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'nuevo-789'; 
    $mail->Subject = "Novedad";
    $mail->Body = $mensaje;
    $de = 'administracion'.$curso;
    $mail->setFrom('tfty@gmail.com','Administración');
    $mail->addAddress('ee@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress('fer@misena.edu.co');
    $mail->MsgHTML($mensaje);
    $mail->CharSet='UTF-8';

    if($mail->send()){
        echo "Enviado";
    }else{
        echo "Problemas al enviar error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    $mensaje = '';
}
```

Solo se da este error, cuando uso código html, en el cual el texto  haga un salto de linea, por ejemplo con la etiqueta de párrafo

y con los 
, pero de resto si no uso nada de html el color de texto no cambia sin importar cuantas veces lo envió

Comment: amigo tu post tiene tus creedenciales :v edita o vuelve a preguntar! y la solucion es html :v colocale la propiedad color:black :v y se pone morado porque es html incompleto y solo lee una propiedad que no estas dentro de los requisitos minimos de un html valido para correo!

Comment: Amigo gracias por la aclaración es decir que tengo un problema a la hora de formular el html? como se cuales son los requisitos mínimos....  es decir que solo no tengo que poner etiquetas html  al azar ? si no que hay una estructura especifica ?  PD: ya no están los credenciales ?, gracias

Comment: colocando los atributos de un html [Anatomía de un documento HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics#Anatom%C3%ADa_de_un_documento_HTML)

Comment: mm gracias, tengo que crear toda la estructura, pensé que el solo interpretaba las etiquetas que usaba, pero veo que es necesario toda la estructura

Comment: @R3d3r82 lo que te comenta el otro usuario es que has compartido tu usuario y contraseña en la propia pregunta. Si de verdad son tus credenciales, deberías cambiar la contraseña lo antes posible porque tu cuenta puede haberse visto comprometida.

Comment: donde dice password y username? todo eso es falso xd, los cambie antes de comentar me asustaron pensé que aparecía en otro lugar. igualmente gracias. por la ayuda (y) saludos

Comment: Ok, si son falsos no pasa nada, era sólo para asegurarnos. No serías el primero (ni el último) que por error publica el usuario/contraseña real y luego se encuentra con problemas.